# Clicking a list view item and passing a database item ID to the next activity?

Tags: android, listviewitem

I have an activity which contains a list view which is loaded from an `SQLiteDatabase`.  What I want to happen is, when I click one of the items, I want a second activity to load and display the Item ID.  This is what I have so far:

**setOnItemClickListener:**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Detail.class);
            intent.putExtra("DB_ID_EXTRA",IWantThisToBeMyID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

populating IWantThisToBeMyID:

```
public static String IWantThisToBeMyID = "com.example.projectloc.assignment.pictures._id";
```

**Detail.class**

```
public class Detail extends AppCompatActivity{
String passedVar = null;
private TextView passedView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.dbIDEx);

    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passedText);
    passedView.setText(passedVar);
}
```

When I click one of the list view items it loads the new activity but displays nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out when you add data in `intent` you are adding **`DB_ID_EXTRA`** `key` name and in your **`Detail`** activity your are using **`Master.dbIDEx`** different `key`

> You need to use same key name when passing data through `intent`

Use this

```
passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra("DB_ID_EXTRA");
```

Instead of

```
passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.dbIDEx);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, will mark this as the answer in 9 minutes when SO lets me <3.  Have a happy new year

Comment: @JamLis  Merry Christmas & happy new year happy to help you

Comment: Done :) All the best

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra("DB_ID_EXTRA");
```

**Instead**

```
passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra(Master.dbIDEx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pass the key is **DB_ID_EXTRA** and getting value from intent with wrong key. just change this

```
public class Detail extends AppCompatActivity{
String passedVar = null;
private TextView passedView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);    
    passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra("DB_ID_EXTRA");
    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passedText);
    passedView.setText(passedVar);
 }
```